# Built-in microphone level auto adjusts itself

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, audio, microphone

My built in microphone in MacBook Air 13″ (2017) keeps adjusting itself to the maximum volume each time I have video/audio enabled in Google Chrome (or any other browser except Safari). This happens in Skype (mic auto adjusting function is turned off) as well.

It is so annoying that I must disable microphone anytime something happens, or someone else is talking in my apartment. Because of this I cannot have meetings with my partners and work properly.

Comment: How are you verifying that it's "Adjusting itself to the max point"?

Answer (score 1):

If you haven’t already, try resetting the NVRAM and attempting to replicate the issue. Here’s an Apple support article on what an NVRAM resets does and how to do one.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063

If the issue continues, create a new user account and attempt to replicate the issue in that account. If the issue persists in a test user account than, I’d advise visiting an Apple Store for them to run audio diagnostics and determine if you are having a hardware issue or if your operating system needs to be reinstalled.The article below highlights creating another user.

https://support.apple.com/kb/PH25796?locale=en_US